# Open gnome-terminal on an network namespace and then run a command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm using coreemu to to create a virtual network. I can open a terminal on a specific node with

```
gnome-terminal -e "vcmd -c /tmp/pycore.49330/n1 -- bash"
```

but I would like to open the terminal there, and then have that terminal run a command. I've played around, trying to get the terminal to open and just "echo test" but nothing I've tried works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
gnome-terminal -e "vcmd -c /tmp/pycore.49330/n1 -- bash -c 'date; read'"
```

to execute `date`.

Comment: I tried something similar before and just tried what you suggested. A window opens for a split second before closing.

Comment: Using `read` prevents closing the terminal. It can also be done with a gnome-terminal preference.

Comment: I swear I tried that. I must have messed up the apostrophes somewhere. Thank you.